# error when trying to print associative array element in smarty template

Tags: php, smarty, associative-array, http-status-code-500

I have smarty 4.3 and php 8.1. I have this php array:

```
array(4) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(16) "blah@example.com"
  ["realname"]=>
  string(4) "blah"
  ["alert_email"]=>
  string(16) "blah@example.com"
  ["okta_username"]=>
  string(16) "blah@example.com"
}
```

and this assignment:

```
$smarty->assign('user_info', $okta_user);
```

To reproduce, you would need Smarty 4.3 and this:

```
<?php

$okta_user = array(
'username' => 'blah@example.com',
'realname' => 'blah',
'alert_email' => 'blah@example.com',
'okta_username' => 'blah@example.com',
);
$smarty->assign('user_info', $okta_user);

$smarty->display('myfile.tpl');
?>
```

In the smarty template (tpl) file I have this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
   <tr>
     <td>user</td>
     <td>{$user_info.okta_username}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this 500 error in nginx:

```
PHP message: {"message":"Uncaught Exception TypeError: \"Cannot access offset of type string on string\" at /htdocs/files/templates_c/ce629fe8ee999420d3ca3688e712adb8f5e4083e_0.file.myfile.tpl.php
```

If I change the line in the table  to:

```
<td>{$user_info}</td>
```

the page renders and I see this in the table:

```
{"username":"blah@example.com","realname":"blah","alert_email":"blah@example.com","okta_username":"blah@example.com"}
```

All the documentation I find, such as this official documentation page https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl, indicate that *$user_info.okta_username* is the way to refer to this associative array key. I don't understand why I get this 500 error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: @Progman I just edited it. Is it good now?

Comment: Are you sure that, when you `assign` the array, that `$okta_user` is still an array? Seems that it is recognized as a string by smarty

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi I think you found the problem. It looks like it was later getting changed to a json-encoded string. Great catch!

Comment: Hi @raphael75 It is working fine with data and information you have provided. Sometimes, issues can arise from template compilation. Clear your Smarty template cache or recompile your templates to ensure they are up to date.